# Is there a server-less way I can consume the MSK Kafka topics content into an S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-kafka

Is there a *server-less way* I can consume the Kafka topics content into an S3 bucket ?
(with or without kinesis)

I have :

1. AWS MSK kafka - it gets data from multiple topic sources
2. S3 bucket.

I want to take the data generated by the MSK Kafka topics, and save it to S3 (for archiving).
one way to do it is to use kinesis firehose.
I succeeded applying this work flow using MSK kafka kinesis connector.
(https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/kinesis-kafka-connector-msk/)

Problem is, I don't like this solution, because it is not server-less.
I have to use EC2 to run the connector and the kafka client on it.

I find it odd that I have 2 AWS services (meaning server-less) but for them to talk between themselves , I need to have a server to run on it processes (kafka kinesis connector + kafka client).

For example I thought of a filebeat (which will run on ECS fargate) to TAKE the data from MSK and put it in S3, but I'm afraid there will be performance issues with this solution.

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: You can do this with Confluent Cloud and the managed connectors - but if your data is in MSK then you won't be able to use that option. If you're looking at deploying your own option then the Kafka Connect S3 connector is useful to consider - here's how you'd run it (not serverless though): https://rmoff.net/2021/01/11/running-a-self-managed-kafka-connect-worker-for-confluent-cloud/

Comment: Thanks Robin for your quick reply :-) 
I'd rather use a free open source solution though.

Comment: Kafka Connect is part of Apache Kafka (Apache 2.0) and the S3 connector is [Confluent Community Licenced](https://www.confluent.io/confluent-community-license-faq/) (source available)

Comment: Thanks :-) good to know

Comment: How'd you do it in the end?